# List AD Groups this computer is a member of

Tags: windows-7

Is there a command or script that can output a list of AD Groups only it's (local computer) a member of. It will need to run on Windows 7 workstations, preferably without the need for AD cmdlets or the admin pack.

I'm sure the computers must store this information somewhere locally, it's just a matter of where.

Any suggestions welcomed

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

The ad group membership of the computer is not stored localy.
What you can do is to write a vbs script that uses adsi to first find the computer name and then do a search for it in ad and then retrieve the memberOf attribute.

I bet there is good examples already out there